# VBA Case Select Multiple Conditions

Tags: vba, excel

New to VBA.  I'm attempting to build a value of Dimensions (pulling from two different cells in an excel spreadsheet in which one might be larger than the other, and I always want the lower number first) in which the output (a string which will be concatenated with strings from other functions) might be one of the following:

4868 (no x separating the integer values)
48x60.5 (with x separating an integer and real number)
36.5x60 (with x separating a real number and an integer)
24.75x72.125 (with x separating a real number and an integer)

Variable types are defined in VBA as Single (not Double).  Here's my code:

```
Function getDimDisplay(h As Single, w As Single) As String

Dim strResult As String
Dim iH As Integer
Dim iW As Integer
Dim strH As Variant
Dim strW As Variant

iH = CInt(h)
iW = CInt(w)

Select Case h
    Case (h >= w And iH = h And iW = w)
        strH = CStr(iH)
        strW = CStr(iW)
        strResult = strW & strH
    Case (h >= w And iH <> h And iW = w)
        strH = CStr(h)
        strW = CStr(iW)
        strResult = strW & "x" & strH
    Case (w >= h And iH = h And iW <> w)
        strH = CStr(iH)
        strW = CStr(w)
        strResult = strH & "x" & strW
    Case (w >= h And iH <> h And iW <> w)
        strH = CStr(h)
        strW = CStr(w)
        strResult = strH & "x" & strW
End Select

getDimDisplay = strResult

End Function
```

It will compile, but it won't return any output.  What gives?

Comment: oops, just realized the last case statement is real number and real number.  Brain belch....

Comment: So... is your problem solved then? If yes, please remove the post or answer it yourself (see the button at the bottom of the screen).

Comment: still tinkering..... it works for most situations, but not all.

Answer (score 8):

your variable 'h' is not a boolean.  However, you're calling it in select case to match conditions which are either true or false.

Change your "select case h" to "select case true".  all else will work ok.

```
Select Case True

Case (h >= w And iH = h And iW = w)
    strH = CStr(iH)
    strW = CStr(iW)
    strResult = strW & strH
Case (h >= w And iH <> h And iW = w)
    strH = CStr(h)
    strW = CStr(iW)
    strResult = strW & "x" & strH
Case (w >= h And iH = h And iW <> w)
    strH = CStr(iH)
    strW = CStr(w)
    strResult = strH & "x" & strW
Case (w >= h And iH <> h And iW <> w)
    strH = CStr(h)
    strW = CStr(w)
    strResult = strH & "x" & strW

End Select
```

Answer (score 2):

Select Case doesn't work like this. It compares the item presented (h) to the values calculated for the individual case statements.

The case statements you have all evaluate to a bool, true or fasle. Whatever h equals, it's not that! For this bit of code, you nedd an if then else if structure.

Comment: the if/then syntax is moving me closer to the goal post.  See comments above about the handling of digits (specifically zeros) after the decimal.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, the closest you can get to the structure youre looking for is this type of thing:

```
Select Case h
Case Is >= w And Is = iH
    If w = iW Then
    '   do stuff
    Else
    '   do other stuff
    End If
Case Is <= w And Is = iH
    If w <> iW Then
    '   do stuff
    End If
Case Is > -w And Is <> iH
    If w <> iW Then
    '   do stuff
    End If
End Select
```

Comment: As noted above, "And" cannot be used with Case statements in VBA.

Comment: @variant this is not exact, after some tests I saw that "And" can always be used except with an "Is" statement on its right

Answer (score 0):

try  this:

```
Function getDimDisplay(h As Single, w As Single) As String
Dim iH%:    iH = CInt(h)
Dim iW%:    iW = CInt(w)

If h >= w And iH = h And iW = w Then
    getDimDisplay = CStr(iW) & CStr(iH)
Else
    If h >= w And iH <> h And iW = w Then
        getDimDisplay = CStr(iW) & "x" & CStr(h)
    Else
        If w >= h And iH = h And iW <> w Then
            getDimDisplay = CStr(iH) & "x" & CStr(w)
        Else
            If w >= h And iH <> h And iW <> w Then
                getDimDisplay = CStr(h) & "x" & CStr(w)
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If
End Function
```

Comment: Sorry to take so long getting back about whether this would work or not.  I have about six irons in the fire, and this (while important to ME) was not important to the boss, so it slipped to the bottom of the priority list.  But, drum roll, it works for MOST situations. Unfortunately, it doesn't for others.  Ironically, there doesn't seem to be a rhyme to the reason.  Buy me a clue about defining the variable with the % in it?

Comment: It appears to choke where the variables are defined from my spreadsheet with all zeros behind the decimal.  In other words, 48.50000 is accurately truncated to 48.5; however, 48.00000 produces no result at all.

Comment: use round function to get rid of zeros like this `getDimDisplay = CStr(round(h,10)) & "x" & CStr(round(w,10))`. `dim iH%` is exacly the same as `dim iH as Integer` just shorten version. read more [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/191713)

Comment: I've actually used round in other situations, but since there's no room for error here, it wasn't appropriate.  My problem had to do with having the correct number of comparison options.  I had four different scenarios in my original example when there should have been eight.  Once I fixed that, all was well in the world.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the error I was seeing with some numbers not being handled correctly.  I was missing a comparison scenario - should have been four comparisons to make instead of three for each h>=w or w>=h situation.  Yay!  Thanks folks!  Here's the working code:

```
Function getDimDisplay(h As Single, w As Single) As String

Dim iH%:    iH = CInt(h)
Dim iW%:    iW = CInt(w)

If h >= w And iH = h And iW = w Then
    getDimDisplay = CStr(w) & CStr(h)
Else
    If h >= w And iH <> h And iW = w Then
        getDimDisplay = CStr(w) & "x" & CStr(iH)
    Else
        If h >= w And iH = h And iW <> w Then
            getDimDisplay = CStr(w) & "x" & CStr(iH)
        Else
            If h >= w And iH <> h And iW <> w Then
                getDimDisplay = CStr(w) & "x" & CStr(h)
            Else
                If w >= h And iH = h And iW = w Then
                    getDimDisplay = CStr(iH) & CStr(iW)
                Else
                    If w >= h And iH <> h And iW = w Then
                        getDimDisplay = CStr(h) & "x" & CStr(iW)
                    Else
                        If w >= h And iH = h And iW <> w Then
                            getDimDisplay = CStr(iH) & "x" & CStr(w)
                        Else
                            If w >= h And iH <> h And iW <> w Then
                                getDimDisplay = CStr(h) & "x" & CStr(w)
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If    
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

In Select case, you can't use "and" operator, instead you have to use a comma ","

```
Select Case h
Case Is >= w , Is = iH
    If w = iW Then
    '   do stuff
    Else
    '   do other stuff
    End If
Case Is <= w , Is = iH
    If w <> iW Then
    '   do stuff
    End If
Case Is > -w , Is <> iH
    If w <> iW Then
    '   do stuff
    End If
End Select
```

Please see the below example for more clarity

http://gadoth.com/excel-vba-series-post-9-select-case/

Comment: This is WRONG: the comma in a select case is an OR, not an AND.

Comment: This answer is very wrong. You can use "And" in a Select Case and the comma is not the equivalent of an "And". It act like if you had an extra Case with the same code after (it kinda act like an "Or"). Check https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-select-case for more details.